# Inclusion-exclusion in a set of multivariables

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion, multivariate-statistical-analysis

I faced a challenge leading me to ask this question:

If we have a set of n random variables, can we apply inclusion-exclusion for this set? Clearly, if we have a portfolio containing $X_{1}$, $X_{2}$, ..., $X_{n}$ that each shows a stock or bond price, and $A_{1}$, $A_{2}$, ..., $A_{n}$ are loss events of $X_{i}$s respectively, can I say that the probability of facing loss, on the whole of the portfolio, is $P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right)$?

If yes, How can you justify the following condition:

The portfolio has two stocks $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ that are mutually exclusive (have strong negative correlation). $P(A_{1})$ and $P(A_{2})$ are greater than 0.5, so the probability of the portfolio's loss would be greater than $1$ since $P(A_{1}\cup A_{2})$ = $P(A_{1})$ + $P(A_{2}) \geq 1$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle explains the inclusion-exclusion principle for multiple variables. In general `P(a1 union a2) = P(a1) + P(a2) - P(a1 intersect a2)`

Comment: $P(A_1\cup A_2)=P(A_1)+P(A_2)$ if $A_1$ and $A_2$ are *mutually exclusive* (not independent) and if that is the case then it is not possible that $P(A_i)>0.5$ for $i=1,2$. Further in general we have $P(A_1\cup A_2)=P(A_1)+P(A_2)-P(A_1\cap A_2)$ by means of inclusion/exclusion.

Comment: Okay, but as I said: $P(A_i)>0.5$ for $i=1,2$ is not possible then.